# Is it possible to write tuples to excel using xlswriter

Tags: python, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7.6. I want to take a tuple (of 4 lists) and write these to columns (in ascending order) to excel using a loop

I am able to successfully write to the excel using individual lists 
e.g.

```
i += 1
wksheet.write(i,48,lista)
wksheet.write(i,49,listb)
wksheet.write(i,50,listc)
wksheet.write(i,51,listd)
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this using a tuple of the lists a->d and a loop or something similar? i.e. In the case the number of lists is much larger.
I tried the following but I got an error: **TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable**

```
# Want to write to excel lista in column1, listb in column 2 etc..
k = 0
tuple = (lista,listb,listc,listd)
for num in range(1,4):
    wksheet.write(k,num,tuple(k))
    k += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should avoid 'tuple' as a name of your tuple since it is a built-in type and this is considered bad coding practice.

In order to get element k from the tuple you need to use [] not (). I would write the code as follows ('col' is the tuple index and 'row' is the list index).

```
tup = (lst1, lst2, lst3, ..., n)
for (col, lst) in enumerate(tup):
    for (row, value) in enumerate(lst):        
        wksheet.write(row+1, col+1, value)
```