# How to write a list of tuple to excel

Tags: python, excel, tuples

I have loop results from my previous codes, for example:
`((1.1, 2.1, 3.1), (1.2, 2.2, 3.2), (1.3, 2.3, 3.3), 1, 2, 3)
 ((1.4, 2.4, 3.4), (1.5, 2.5, 3.5), (1.6, 2.6, 3.6), 4, 5, 6)
 ((1.7, 2.7, 3.7), (1.8, 2.8, 3.8), (1.9, 2.9, 3.9), 7, 8, 9)`

What I expect is to write the results to excel, and put each element in the cell of each row (treat each tuple as one element). Like this:

```
Name         Name1            Name2            Name3      Name4  Name5  Name6
Number1 (1.1, 2.1, 3.1)  (1.2, 2.2, 3.2)  (1.3, 2.3, 3.3)   1      2      3
Number2 (1.4, 2.4, 3.4)  (1.5, 2.5, 3.5)  (1.6, 2.6, 3.6)   4      5      6
Number3 (1.7, 2.7, 3.7)  (1.8, 2.8, 3.8)  (1.9, 2.9, 3.9)   7      8      9
```

I have tried these two ways but failed:[Answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34069015/is-it-possible-to-write-tuples-to-excel-using-xlswriter?rq=1)  [Answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32915172/how-to-write-a-list-of-tuple-in-python-with-header-mapping)
Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can get the csv of list of tuple

```
import csv

with open('text.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    fwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)

    for x in sorted_list:
        fwriter.writerow(x)
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but when I run the codes there is a TypeError in the last line called a bytes-like object is required, not 'str', do you know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You want to represent each tuple as a string, because Excel doesn't understand python tuples. One way to do this is to use str to convert it into a string.

```
>>> str((1.1, 2.1, 3.1))
'(1.1, 2.1, 3.1)'
```

Comment: Could you please explain it in detail a little bit? I am not so familiar with python:(

Comment: You you please update with your post with your code? It is difficult to answer without knowing the context of this within your code.

Comment: Sorry, the whole codes are too long and contain 4 files. You can just assume that I have some lists of tuples as I posted and write it to excel. Thank you.